# ¿Como agregar un efecto de animacion en el dropDown de bootstrap 4?

Tags: html5, bootstrap-4

Tengo el siguiente código y intento agregarle un efecto down al dropdown para cuando le den click me lo deslice hacia abajo lento.

```html
 <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a   class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
```

El código que he intentado usar es el siguiente:

```js
  $('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown', function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideDown();
  });
  $('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideUp();
  });
```

Como ven el código sencillamente aplico una animación de show al hide para mostrar y ocultar mi dropdown pero no funciona alguien tiene alguna idea de como solucionar este tipo de problema?

Igualmente intente aplicar el siguiente código:

```js
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $( document.body ).click(function () {
  if ( $( "div:dropdown-menu" ).is( ":hidden" ) ) {
    $( ".dropdown-menu" ).slideDown( "slow" );
  } else {
    $( ".dropdown-menu" ).hide();
  }
});
</script>
```

NOTA:
 Agregué todos los links de bootstrap y Jquery.

[fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115833/adding-a-slide-effect-to-bootstrap-dropdown)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Con `slideToggle()` funciona bien. Te dejo un ejemplo:

```js
$('.dropdown').on('show.bs.dropdown',function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideToggle(1000);
});

$('.dropdown').on('hide.bs.dropdown',function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).slideToggle(1000);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a   class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
```